# Android - How can I show camera in 2 or more views

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to create an Android app based on camera.
I want to split my screen into 2 or 4 views. (when 2 views are show, one will be above and one will be below. And when 4 views, 2 will be on top (side by side) and 2 will be at bottom (side by side))
I want to show the what camera is seeing in all the views.
I mean all the views must render according to camera.
Is it possible? HOw?

Answer (score 0):

This is not practical AFAIK. The camera will draw to only one `SurfaceView`, not four. While you could try to make a mock `SurfaceView` that then passes the information to four separate `SurfaceViews`, your performance probably will be awful.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this being possible is having `setPreviewCallback()` method take those frames, converting them to bitmaps or jpegs, and then drawing those images on the other surface views.  I'm with CommonsWare though.  It will be slow and painful.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually did that in my app Face Costume:
[Face Costume](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bengigi.facecostume)

What I did was use the camera preview buffer, convert it from YUV to RGB, and render it on an OpenGL texture. You don't have to choose OpenGL, you can also do it using the regular canvas method.

On dual core tablets it works well... haven't tested it on other hardware.

Comment: how cool. do you have any samples or links that you got to learn how to do it?